# Hide changesets from merge dialogs in TFS 2008 (2010)?

Tags: user-interface, tfs, merge, branch

When merging from one branch to another, we can see which changesets are present in one branch, and yet not merged over to the other.

Some of these changesets aren't supposed to be merged. Is it possible to hide these?

Or do we just have to edit the changeset comments to include a prefix, like "NOMERGE:", to visually filter them out?

The reason I ask is that from time to time a developer forgets to merge changes that were supposed to be merged, and it's a bit hard to find these in a forest of other changesets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TF MERGE /DISCARD option

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2009/03/09/how-to-use-tf-merge-discard.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange question, why are some changesets not supposed to be merged and how do you determine those. If you are doing selective merges to me it looks like the branches are not created properly. I don't think you can hide changesets using Visual Studio. Using TF.exe command line application however you can find out what changesets are candidates in a merge and then merge individual changesets selectively see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx

Comment: It is actually very common to branch a project then need to modify config files, build/deploy scripts, etc to point at similarly branched datasources/servers for a completely separate development/testing environment while building a new feature/product. And then when merging back to trunk we normally what to skip the initial branch-setup changesets. Making it so TFS knows to not include those changes in the merge is incredibly useful.

Comment: @Arkaine55 You can also do the merge, but for the config files specify "keep target" in the "Resolve Conflicts" dialog. It still marks the file as having been merged.